# ngx-toastr, Toast not showing in Angular

Tags: angular, toastr

I'm developing a web app using Angular and I wanted to include ngx-toastr to send notifications to users, but it isn't working as expected. When I trigger a toast nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

My code is below:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
    private toast: ToastrService,
  ) { }
  
  test() {
    this.toast.success("I'm a toast!", "Success!");
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsfroy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I could see the toast when I clicked `Make a toast` button. Just that it disappears in around a second

Comment: but i want to display that bottom right with success background

Comment: Please look at my answer

Answer (score 8):

You missed to add the `css` needed by the toast.

Add in the styles array of `angular.json` like below

```
   "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
```

Look at the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exexqp) here

Comment: Adding `@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';` in styles.css is worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

**In your styles.css add**

```
@import "toastr";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss", 
  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css" // try adding '../' if you're using angular cli before 6
]
```

Then run `npm install` before you run `npm start` or `ng serve`.